# Retention management for time-series table in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table which I use DMS to migrate from Aurora to Redshift. This table is insert only with a lot of data by timestamp.
I would like to have a trimmed version of that table in redshift.

The idea was to use partitions on it and use retention script to keep it with just the last 2 months. However in Redshift there is no partitions and what I find out there time-series table which sounds the same. If I understand it correctly my table should look like:

```
create table public."bigtable"(
"id" integer  NOT NULL DISTKEY,
"date" timestamp,
"name" varchar(256) 
)
 SORTKEY(date);
```

However I don't find good documentation how the retention is managed. Would like any corrections and advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways this is typically done in Redshift.

For small to medium tables the data can just be DELETEd and the table VACUUMed (usually a delete only vacuum).  Redshift is very good at handling large amounts of data and for tables that are really large this works fine.  There is some overhead for the delete and vacuum but if these are scheduled on off hours it works just fine and is simple.

When the table in question get really big or there are not low workload times to perform the delete and vacuum, people set up "month" tables for their data and use a view that UNION ALLs these tables together.  Then "removing" a month is just redefining the view and dropping the unneeded table.  This is very low effort for Redshift to perform but is a bit more complex to set up.  Your incoming data needs to be put into the correct table based on month so it is no longer just a copy from Aurora.  This process also simplifies UNLOADing the old tables to S3 for history capture purposes.

Comment: that can be done, that question remaining how does DMS knows to which table push the data?

Comment: I've used DMS a few times and find is lacking for many such real-world situations.  Many AWS higher end services are 70% solutions - they work for the basic cases but any significant complexity and they don't have the capabilities.  I don't know of a way to get DMS to do this - its mission is to copy tables exactly.  This is the source of my "a bit more complex to set up" comment.  Others may have greater expertise with DMS and some other ideas but IHMO what you are trying to do will mean moving away from DMS.